# Confused with read() system call

Tags: c, system, inotify

I am very confused with `read()` calls to get inotify events.

Here is the code:

```
#define EVENT_SIZE sizeof(inotify_event)
int fd = inotify_init();
int wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, dir, IN_MODIFY);
void* p = malloc(sizeof(EVENT_SIZE));
read(wd, p, (EVENT_SIZE + 10));
```

My test file is `a.txt`.
The output after debug in gdb is:

`{wd = 0, mask = 0, cookie = 0, len = 0, name = 0x558f05d002d0 ""}`

Now, when I change the last line to `read(fd, p, (EVENT_SIZE + 16));`, the output that I get in gdb is:

`{wd = 1, mask = 2, cookie = 0, len = 16, name = 0x5625cdd422d0 ".a.txt.swp"}`

Q1. Why don't I get an overflow error because in both cases, I am writing more than the allocated buffer `p`?

Q2. If there is no error, then my first program should also work because my filename is less than 10, but it doesn't work and it only works with 16. What am I missing here?

compiler - `g++ 9.3.0`

os - `ubuntu 20.04`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The behaviour of writing outside the boundaries of an array is **undefined**. Additionally, `read` reads **up to** the given number of bytes.
2. ???

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

1. You get a segfault, if your process attempts to access a memory address that does not belong to it.
2. malloc - "Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2)."
3. sbrk - "sbrk() increments the program's data space by increment bytes."

From 1., 2. and 3.: There is (probably) room left where you are able to write to, but the data (if any) after your allocated memory is definitely corrupted!

**Q2**

Read the documentation for [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

The meaning of the fields for inotify_event structure:

> **mask** contains bits that describe the event that occurred (see below).

and

> The **len** field counts all of the bytes in name, including the null bytes; the length of each inotify_event structure is thus `sizeof(struct inotify_event)+len`.

and

> The **name** field is present only when an event is returned for a file inside a watched directory; it identifies the filename within the watched directory.  This filename is null-terminated, and may include further null bytes ('\0') to align subsequent reads to a suitable address boundary.

and

> The behavior when the buffer given to read(2) is too small to return information about the next event depends on the kernel version: in kernels before 2.6.21, read(2) returns 0; since kernel 2.6.21, read(2) fails with the error EINVAL.  Specifying a buffer of size `sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1` will be sufficient to read at least one event.